# Calculating PPM from substance in enclosed but ventilated environment

Tags: pressure, gas

Firstly my apologies if this question doesn't have all required data or is impossible to answer!

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to determine the ppm of vapor from a particular liquid if left in an enclosed space at atmospheric pressure. I have a safety datasheet for the liquid showing a vapor pressure of 82.06mbar and density of $0.82\ g/cm^3$, at $20^\circ C$.

Is this enough to work out a PPM value in atmosphere, or is it not possible without actual in-situ ppm measurement?

Comment: Is the air in the enclosed space at 20 deg C?  Is this an equilibrium situation, where as much of the liquid has evaporated as possible and there is a small amount of exposed liquid in a container that doesn't evaporate?  Do you want a ppm value based on weight or volume?

Comment: Hi David, For now assuming the air is 20 deg C yes. Yes I guess it would be an equilibrium situation. PPM based on volume I'm thinking. I am scoping out the feasibility of whether this value could be obtained in theory, for a piece of manufacturing equipment that has vats of this liquid inside a chamber. We may need to know the ppm concentration of it in the atmosphere within the chamber.  Pardon my lack of physics/chemistry understanding, thats why I'm posting on here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system is in equilibrium, which means that the partial pressure of the contaminant is 82.06 mbar.  In SI units, this equates to 8206 Pa.  Since standard atmospheric pressure is 101325 Pa, the ratio of these two pressures gives a mole fraction of 0.081, which is 8.1 mole%, which is equivalent to 8.1 vol%, assuming that the contaminant acts like an ideal gas.  Converting to ppm gives a value of 80,100 ppm on a volume basis.

Note that this concentration assumes equilibrium, which will be an unventilated condition.  A ventilated condition will definitely be non-equilibrium, and will depend on numerous variables, such as the concentration of the contaminant in the incoming air, the velocity and temperature of the ventilation air, whether that air blows directly on a puddle of the contaminant (aka location of the ventilation), etc.  A calculation based on a ventilated condition will depend on several assumptions, which will make the calculation uncertain.  For such a ventilated condition, it would make sense to actually make measurements.